# How to hide input in xml?

Tags: html, css, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm confused, if the code in the html is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="123">
```

So how's that code in xml?
I'm just learning xml, but I'm stuck in this element, if in html it has type="hidden" and value="123" then what does xml have? How to use type="hidden" and value="123" in xml?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just add hidden attributes. The mistake you made is adding type="hidden" instead of just adding "hidden" without type

```html
<input hidden type="text"/>
```

Comment: But bro, not work? Check this: https://j.top4top.io/p_2155tdcjm0.jpg

Comment: The code: <input class='form-control' id='inputMsg' name='message' required='true' type='text' v-model='target.msg'/>

Comment: <input class='form-control' id='inputMsg' name='message' required type='text' v-model='target.msg'/> you should not add required="true", just required is enough, same for hidden